# How to classify very big csv data file based on classifier column by using parallelization?

Tags: python, bash, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have below classification file.

**all_class_file.txt**

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz1
adg
trv
```

**full_data_file.txt**

HEADER = "dt","id","name","class","multiplier","value".
Note:  the data here is just a sample, actual data is in 45-50MB csv file and may contain more than one CSV line in one file. (There are many such files we need to process individually.)

```
"2021-10-16","35","U2","def","50","200000"
"2021-10-16","37","R2","ghi","449","800000"
"2021-10-16","39","D2","jkl","50","1300000"
"2021-10-17","43","P2","vwx","120","200000"
"2021-10-20","42","Y2","mno","70","100000"
"2021-10-21","42","Y2","mno","70","100000"
"2021-10-16","41","S1","stu","50","30000"
"2021-10-16","43","P2","vwx","120","200000"
"2021-10-17","394","D2","jkl","50","1300000"
"2021-10-17","412","S1","stu","50","30000"
"2021-10-22","402","Y2","mno","70","100000"
"2021-10-30","430","P1","vwx","120","200000"
"2021-10-31","430","P1","vwx","120","200000"
"2021-11-14","409","T1","pqr","50","769836"
"2021-11-15","251","Z1","abc","50","100000"
"2021-11-15","404","T1","pqr","50","1000000"
```

Below is the script which classify above big data into multiple files and directories based on date and class columns.

**data_classifier.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

CURR_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})" && pwd)/

_all_class_file="${CURR_DIR}/all_class_file.txt"
_src_file="${CURR_DIR}/full_data_file.txt"

function _code() {
  iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16  > "$1"
}

function _all_dt() {
  cat $2 |  awk -F , '{val=$4;gsub(/\"/,"",val)} val=="'"$1"'"' | awk -F , '{print $1}' | sort -u
}

function _header() {
  echo '"dt","id","name","class","multiplier","value"'
}

function _generate_files() {
  _src_file="$1"
  _tmp_file="${CURR_DIR}/_$(date +%s)_tmp_file_$(date +%H%m%s).$$"


  if [[ ! -f ${_src_file} ]]; then
    echo "File = ${_src_file} does not exist, creating empty file = ${_src_file}"
    touch "${_src_file}"
  fi

  _report_path="${CURR_DIR}/${_data_file}"

  for _class in $(cat "$_all_class_file")
  do
    _days="$(_all_dt "${_class}" "${_src_file}")"
    for _dt_in in ${_days}
    do
      _dt="${_dt_in//\"}"
      cat "${_src_file}" | awk -F"[\",]" '$2=="'"${_dt}"'"' | awk -F , '{val=$4;gsub(/\"/,"",val)} val=="'"${_class}"'"' > "${_tmp_file}"
      _dst_file="${CURR_DIR}/classified/${_class}/data_${_class}_${_dt//-}.csv"
      mkdir -p "$(dirname "${_dst_file}")"
      (_header && cat "${_tmp_file}") | _code "${_dst_file}"

      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        rm -fv "${_tmp_file}"
        return 1
      fi
    done
  done
  rm -fv "${_tmp_file}"
  echo "END _generate_files"
}

_generate_files "$_src_file"
```

Question:
currently I process around 25 big csv file using above logic, and it is using plain bash cat and awk and takes around 3-4 hours, should i use other language like python to make this operation faster by using multithreading techniques of those languages?

Output directory structure and files inside it:

```
├── classified
│   ├── abc
│   │   └── data_abc_20211115.csv
│   ├── def
│   │   └── data_def_20211016.csv
│   ├── ghi
│   │   └── data_ghi_20211016.csv
│   ├── jkl
│   │   ├── data_jkl_20211016.csv
│   │   └── data_jkl_20211017.csv
│   ├── mno
│   │   ├── data_mno_20211020.csv
│   │   ├── data_mno_20211021.csv
│   │   └── data_mno_20211022.csv
│   ├── pqr
│   │   ├── data_pqr_20211114.csv
│   │   └── data_pqr_20211115.csv
│   ├── stu
│   │   ├── data_stu_20211016.csv
│   │   └── data_stu_20211017.csv
│   └── vwx
│       ├── data_vwx_20211016.csv
│       ├── data_vwx_20211017.csv
│       ├── data_vwx_20211030.csv
│       └── data_vwx_20211031.csv
```

Comment: So, basically, you'll be creating one file per CSV line? A modest parallelization may speed up the process, while using too much threads will slow it down.

Comment: @fravadona the data here is just a sample, actual data is in 45-50MB each csv file and may contain more than one CSV line in one file.

Comment: I would start by sorting the csv by `class,dt`. After that, the processing will be smoother and faster, even with single thread.

Comment: Fravadona will try that on my original big file